# Typing on a path but retain the path itself

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am currently trying out typing on a path and I seem not to do what I want.

Is there an option where I could retain the path itself?  I notice that typing on a path removes the path in preview mode.  This is so that I could have a circular text with a circular path in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply reselect the path with the **Direct Selection Tool** and reapply a stroke or fill to it after you've added your text. The path is still there. However, adding Type on a Path to it removes all strokes and fills.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate the path, one will disappear when you edit it and the other remains there.

Doing this duplicate on top trick is used an awful lot in illustrator so there is a shortcut command: Paste in Front; Cmd+F which puts it 'ontop' and Paste in Back; Cmd+B which puts it 'below'. Either one is good for you on this occasion!

Answer (score -1):

Just use the regular type tool rather than the type on path tool. 
Worked for me at least.

Comment: Can you please explain better? Can you add the command to start the tool and can you add a screenshot. What do you mean with "worked for me at last"?